# Getting an error when concatenating

Tags: php, concatenation

This is my code...

```
<?php

$j = 1;
$imgClass = "cname";
$imgSet = 'imgSet'.$j;
$setClass = $imgSet.' '.$imgClass;

$divHtml = '<div class=' . $setClass . '>' .'some text'. '</div>';

echo $divHtml;

?>
```

Desired output was:

```
<div class="imgSet1 cname">some text</div>
```

Current output is:

```
<div class="imgSet1" cname="">some text</div>
```

Not understanding where i went wrong...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually wrapping the `class` in quotes. Your code is perfectly fine otherwise.

Change this:

```
$divHtml = '<div class=' . $setClass . '>' .'some text'. '</div>';
```

To this:

```
$divHtml = '<div class="' . $setClass . '">' .'some text'. '</div>';
```

Comment: seriously.. this was bugging me... i knew it must be something silly.. maybe i am very sleepy working late nights.. thanks buddy...

Comment: It happens! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Missing the double quotes:

```
$divHtml = '<div class="' . $setClass . '">some text</div>';
```

The single quotes around 'some text' aren't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break your code down:

```
$j = 1;
$imgClass = "cname";
$imgSet = 'imgSet'.$j; // "imgSet1"
$setClass = $imgSet.' '.$imgClass; // "imgSet1 cname"

$divHtml = '<div class=' . $setClass . '>' .'some text'. '</div>'; // "<div class=imgSet1 cname>some text</div>"
```

Specifically look closely at what the variables truely are.

I would suggest:

```
$divHtml = "<div class='$setClass'>some text</div>"; // or use =\"..\" in class
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting is human-errorprone. Combining it with concatenation is worse. Try `"` with variable interpolation,

```
 $divHtml = "<div class='$setClass'>some text</div>";
```

or `HEREDOC` syntax (usually for longer strings),

```
$divHtml = <<<EOD
    <div class='$setClass'>some text</div>;
EOD;
```

This avoids scattering small, easily confused marks across your code.